# Ford focus 2005 1.6 dtci cranks but no voltage on injectors

Tags: ford, focus

My ford focus 2005 1.6 tdci cranks but doesn't start. When I check the wires fuses all are in good working conditions.some say its low pressure on the fuel rail. How do I bleed air in the fuel line properly to get the pressure that is required.
Thank you.

Comment: Fuel rails are self bleeding on modern cars and trucks. Voltage might be hard to read unless you have a 10 megohm or higher DVOM.

Comment: If you want to check fuel pressure, you can purchase a fuel pressure gage for fairly cheap. Make sure you find access location for the gage and have the proper fittings to hook it up. You can find what your fuel pressure should be by using a repair manual. The test is taken with key on engine off, then key on engine on, and last with key off engine off. If you truly have no voltage to injectors, looking for fuel pressure wouldn't be the first place to look.